# Exposing an external data connection publicly

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc, google-iam

I have a simple python script that's being called by a remote procedure in BigQuery through an Apache Spark external data connector that's provided by the public preview.

```py
print("Hello World!")
```

I created a remote procedure in BigQuery in a public dataset called `public` using

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
    `tumult-labs.public.helloworld`()
WITH CONNECTION `tumult-labs.us.bigspark` OPTIONS (engine='SPARK',
        main_file_uri='gs://analytics-procedures/helloworld.py')
    LANGUAGE python
```

```sql
CALL `tumult-labs.public.helloworld`()
```

This will simply show up as `Hello World!` in the logs as expected.

I can call this remote procedure from within my organization, but how do I expose the Apache Spark external data connector so that people from outside the organization can call and use my remote procedures as well?

I created a user from outside the organization (A private gmail account) that has been given public preview to the connector, and can create and run the script outlined above. However, when the private gmail account tries to run the `tumult-labs.public.helloworld` procedure, they encounter this error.

```
Access Denied: Connection projects/tumult-labs/locations/us/connections/bigspark: User does not have bigquery.connections.use permission for connection projects/tumult-labs/locations/us/connections/bigspark. at [1:1]
```

The dataset that the remote procedure resides under `tumult-labs.public` is set to allUsers, but the issue now is that there's no permissions to make the external data connection `tumult-labs.us.bigspark` to be public.

Is there a way to set it such that it uses the user's own Apache Spark external data connection or to make `tumult-labs`'s `us.bigspark` to be public?